# How to impliment auth in laravel 5.2 with user role?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

How to impliment auth in laravel 5.2 with user role,
use admin and users prefix according to the role of the users

Answer (score 0):

there are plenty of custom plugins available to achieve this, however each is different when it comes to process ACL, after a deep research about all the plugins, I have found the following plugin which is light weight, simple and easy to customize as you want

[Entrust ACl](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/tree/master#installation)